# MKAnnotationView Swift Adding "Info" button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am very new to swift (coming from python) I am struggling with creating a MKAnnotationView. I followed a tutorial by ray wenderlich but the code appears to be outdated. The function call does not seem to work or produce the "i" intended to be in the annotation of the pin. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
import MapKit

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

// 1
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if let annotation = annotation as? Artwork {
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = MapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MKPinAnnotationView { // 2
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            // 3
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            let button = UIButton(type:.detailDisclosure)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button as UIView
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
    }
}
```

I am running Xcode 8.1, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am using Xcode 8.1 and Swift  3.0 . For Some reason Delegate methods are not firing until you set delegate in storyboard:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {return nil}

        let reuseId = "pin"

        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
            let calloutButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
            pinView!.sizeToFit()
        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }


        return pinView
    }
```

for button Action

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
          print("button tapped")
        }
    }
```

I am attaching sample project for your issue

[Map Sample Project Swift 3. 0 Xcode 8.1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52jrbm0xjubwc4s/MapSample.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I'm getting the following errors:                                                                                            from having MapView.delegate = self in my ViewController it fails as _cannot assign value to type 'View Controller ' to type 'MKMapView Delegate?'_

Comment: this is a sample . and Swift 3 code . Change it to Swift lower version of your rquirement

Comment: I believe I am running swift 3

Comment: I made the Class a delegate of MKMapView Delegate and the build ran fine but still no button on the right hand side. Any Ideas?

Comment: Give me sometime am preparing a sample for you . please hold on

Comment: Updated a sample source and the fix is set delegate in storyboard. Sample another way of using  mapview

Comment: Works Perfect Thanks!